# Two session values passing to another page in session in classic asp

Tags: session, asp-classic

Two session values passing to another page in session.
    I got 2 session values like  abcdabcd, asasas

```
strHTML = strHTML & "<td style='width:220px'><b>" &  replace(aParameters(1),"£","&pound;") &  "</b></td>"& vbcrlf

keyArrays=replace(aParameters(1),"£","&pound;").value+","
            Session("netrtt")=  Split(keyArrays,",")  
            For counter = 0 To UBound(Session("netrtt"))  
    Response.Write Session("netrtt")(`enter code here`counter) & ","
Next 
Session("amount")=totalcost
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td width='100%' colspan='4' align='right'>"

strHTML = strHTML & "<b>Total Cost4 :  </b></td>"

if work="show" then
strHTML = strHTML & "<td  ><b> "
strHTML = strHTML & cardcurrency1 &FormatNumber(totalCost,2)  &"</b></td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td ></td>"
else
strHTML = strHTML & "<td ><b>"& cardcurrency1 & totalCost &"</b></td>"
end if
'strHTML = strHTML & "</table>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</tr></form>"
'strHTML = strHTML & "<img border=0 src='worldpay logos/secure_payments.gif' >"
     'strHTML = strHTML & "</td><td><center> <img border=1 src=images/"& flagurl &"><br>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<br></td>" 
    strHTML = strHTML & "</tr></table>"
```

My next page passing a session values like, but i got errors

```
<%=(session("netrtt"))%>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Session("netrtt1")=replace(aParameters(1),"£","&pound;")
   Session("netrtt")=  Split(Session("netrtt1"),",")  
            For counter = 0 To UBound(Session("netrtt"))  
   Response.Write Session("netrtt")(counter) & ", "  I got two values from above mentioned codes. for example like edsfd,dsdsd, but i remove last commas

Comment: Hi , I got answer from below For counter = 0 To UBound(Session("netrtt"))  
            if counter=0 then 
   Response.Write Session("netrtt")(counter)
   else
   Response.Write  ", " & Session("netrtt")(counter) 
   end if but how to remove comma(,) from starting point.

Comment: I got result for : , asdasdasd,asdsadadsad,sadsadasd but i need delete first comma only . any help